# Getbulk operation with list of Oids as input

Tags: snmp

The problem
I am using snmp4j libraries and built a snmp connector
I have created two operations one using the Getbulk and one with Get. Both take in a list of OID's. Both work as attended with out problems. The only problem I am having is on network devices very far way. It takes exactly the same time for each of them. right at 2 minutes. I feel like this is a very long wait time. Although on devices that are close it is very fast and under 5 seconds.

The question

I am wondering does the Getbulk not ask for all the information at once and then comes back with all the information. Or does it ask for each of the OID's in the list one at a time. The same as the Get?

Is there a way to make one call to get all the information I need with one call to the device or is only that I can make repeated calls to the device?

Do I have other options?
Does any body have working java example to achieve this.

Comment: Then you probably should go back to the basics to learn what exactly is GET BULK, https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3416#page-14 Without a definition from you on "all information" it is impossible to answer "Is there a way to make one call to get all the information I need". Note that UDP messages do have size limits, so if you ask for too much, you cannot merely use one call.

Comment: Can we pass  list of oids to getbulk operation and get the values back in a single call to the device.